# Dynamically add hierarchy of input elements and retrieve values in php or jsp

Tags: php, jquery, jsp, database-design

I have a database structure as follows:

```
 tbl_topic                                 tbl_chapter
 -pk id (AutoIncrement)                    -pk id
 -fk parent_id  (references itself)        -chapter_name
 -fk chapter_id (references tbl_chapter)
 -name
 -description
 -teaching_hours
 -teaching_periods
```

There are chapters of a subject and chapters have topics (topics may have subtopic and so on).
First, I need to design a form where user could add topic to a particular chapter, something like below:

```
  Chapter 1: Science: (Add topic +)
    1.Topic:   Name:_____  Description: _____ Hours _____(Add topic +)
       Topic   Name:_____  Description: _____ Hours _____(Add topic +)
          Topic   Name:_____  Description: _____ Hours _____(Add topic +)
    2.Topic:   Name:_____  Description: _____ Hours _____(Add topic +)
       Topic   Name:_____  Description: _____ Hours _____(Add topic +)
```

I just need an algorithm or steps or a hint on how to insert elements hierarchically and get this hierarchy of elements in some language like php or jsp. Also, if this database design is not good, please suggest me a better way to structure it.

Comment: suggest you create html layout and base css first then is not hard to loop over database query to parse data into html format once you have it defined. If already have host need to use language they have available

Answer (score 0):

Here what i am doing in my project

Dealing with news objects on home page .News will come from database as a json string

then

```
if(!(news ==null)){
         for(var i=0; i < news.list.length; i++){
        $(news.list[i]).attr("clientid" ,i);
        var listItemDiv = $("<li id="+news.list[i].clientid+"><h3>"+news.list[i].title+"</h3><span class=date>Department:"+getDepartmentName(news.list[i])+" "+getSubDepartMentName(news.list[i])+"<span><span class=date>Opening Date:"+news.list[i].startDate+"<span><a target='_blank' style='float:right' href='docdetails?docid="+news.list[i].id+" ' >Read More..</a></li></br>");
            $('#newsitems').append($(listItemDiv));

        }
```

in your case you have another loop to iterate `chapter.list object`s

good luck .